# ToUnicodeEx fills buffer with zeroes and returns 1

Tags: windows, winapi, keyboard, keyboard-layout

I use ToUnicodeEx function to translate scancode and virtual key code to Unicode character. In most cases it works as described in [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/query/dev10.query?appId=Dev10IDEF1&l=EN-US&k=k%28TOUNICODEEX%29;k%28SOLUTIONITEMSPROJECT%29;k%28SOLUTIONITEMSPROJECT%29;k%28DevLang-%22C%2b%2b%22%29&rd=true). But on some keys in some keyboard layouts ToUnicodeEx fills buffer with zeros but returns 1. According to MSDN it means one character written to the buffer. But first value in buffer contain 0. How I should interpret such values combinations?

I have found such behavior in following conditions:

- Arabic (102) (00010401) scancode: 0x1f, virtual key: 0x53 'S', Shift pressed, other modifiers not pressed.
- Inuktitut - Latin (0000085d) scancode: 0x1b, virtual key: 0xdd VK_OEM_6, Shift pressed, CapsLock is on, other modifiers not pressed.

Microsoft Keyboard Layout Creator loads these layouts without errors. On Arabic (102) key with problem is empty. On Inuktitut - Latin layout key with problem contains curly brace character '}'.

I do not understand, how Keyboard Layout Creator reads this character.

Answer (score 0):

Looks legit. Key produces `U+0000 Null` char for key in this layout/state. You can skip it.

I think if these keys where defined as `WCH_NONE` then `ToUnicode` would return 0.

[image]

https://learn.microsoft.com/globalization/keyboards/kbda2

http://kbdlayout.info/kbda2

[image]

https://learn.microsoft.com/globalization/keyboards/kbdiulat

http://kbdlayout.info/kbdiulat

"Inuktitut - Latin" is special in terms that it uses `SGCAPS` feature:

> Some keyboards do not associate the CapsLock and Shift keys together for all keystrokes; instead, pressing the CapsLock key defines an additional two shift states for specific keys. Therefore, some languages cannot by typed without the CapsLock key. The "SG" in the name orginiates from the first keyboard layout to use the functionality, the Swiss German keyboard layout.

See http://kbdlayout.info/features/SGCAPS for more info.

Answer (score 0):

It is [a bug in MSKLC](https://metacpan.org/dist/UI-KeyboardLayout/view/lib/UI/KeyboardLayout.pm#MSKLC-keyboards-handle-Ctrl-Shift-letter,-Ctrl-@-(x00)-,-Ctrl-%5E-(x1e)-and-Ctrl-_-(x1f)-differently-than-US-keyboard) that *it does not* produce such events more regularly.  Say, on “English (US)” keyboard such events are produced on `Ctrl-2` and `Ctrl-Shift-2` keypresses.  The complete list of such “funny keys” is on [this section of documentation](https://metacpan.org/dist/UI-KeyboardLayout/view/lib/UI/KeyboardLayout.pm#Keyboard-input-on-Windows,-Part-III:-Customary-%E2%80%9Cspecial%E2%80%9D-keybindings-of-typical-keyboards).

(With these bindinds, one can deliver any `ASCII` codepoint to the application.)